# VideoView onPrepared is not called if the VideoView is invisible

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am hiding the `VideoView` initially and when the video is loaded I am showing the `VideoView`. But `onPrepared` is never called if the `VideoView` is `invisible` initially. However `onPrepared` is called properly if `VideoView` is visible. Is there any way to hide the `videoView` until video is loaded. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        videoView.requestFocus();

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "on prepared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                 videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        });


}
```

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: @J.Kowalski Check the answers :)

Comment: I solved it using your original approach but I made the layout that held the videoview invisible instead of the videoview itself :)

Comment: Oh nice :) I should have tried that in the beginning

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try setting alpha channel of video view to 0 or close to 0.

Comment: This trick works only if you use [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) to load the video. It doesn't work with normal `VideoView`. Anyway thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I used a FrameLayout as a wrapper for the video view and set the wrapper Alpha to 0 before setting its Visibility to Visible and inside the onPreparedListener return the video view wrapper's alpha  back to 1. The View.setAlpha is only available since API 11.

Comment: what do you mean by *Alpha* here? I am unable to understand the term `Alpha` in the whole context.

Comment: @MrNarendra It is just opacity. See this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)

Answer (score 5):

Solved it making its layout invisible instead of videoView itself.
Thanks to @J.Kowalski .

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>
</FrameLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

Set OnPreparedListener:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```

Show progress bar before ready:

```
@Override
public void showProgress() {
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    layoutVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Load video URI:

```
@Override
public void loadVideo(Uri uri) {
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
}
```

When its ready, onPrepared is called:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d("debug", "onPrepared");
    iStepPreviewPresenter.onVideoViewReady();
}
```

Finally show layout and start video:

```
@Override
public void hideProgress() {
    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    layoutVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void startVideo() {
    videoView.start();
}
```

Nailed it!

Answer (score 4):

It can be achieved by one of these tricks

1. You can set the height and width of the `VideoView` to `1px` until the video is prepared and then switch to full screen by changing the properties to `match parent`
2. As @FDIM said in his answer, we can set the alpha value of the view to 0 until video is prepared. But it works only if we use [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) to load the video. It doesn't work with normal `VideoView`. Here is a custom VideoView extending `TextureView` which mimics the default `VideoVideo` implementation. This class can be directly used in xml file and can set the alpha to 0 to hide the video.

   ```
   public class TextureVideoView extends TextureView  implements SurfaceTextureListener                {

   private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

   public TextureVideoView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       init();
   }

   public TextureVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init();
   }

   private void init() {
       mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
       this.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
   }

   public void seekTo(int msec) {
       mMediaPlayer.seekTo(msec);
   }

   public void setVideoPath(final String path) throws IOException {
       mMediaPlayer.reset();
       mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
       mMediaPlayer.prepare();
   }

   public void setVideoPath(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length) throws IOException {
       mMediaPlayer.reset();
       mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fd, offset, length);
       mMediaPlayer.prepare();
   }

   public void setVideoURI(Context context, Uri uri) throws IOException {
       mMediaPlayer.reset();
       mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
   }

   public void setOnPreparedListener(OnPreparedListener onPreparedListener) {
       mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(onPreparedListener);
   }

   public void setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener) {
       mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
   }

   public void setOnErrorListener(OnErrorListener onErrorListener) {
       mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(onErrorListener);
   }

   public void start() {
       mMediaPlayer.start();
   }

   public void pause() {
       mMediaPlayer.pause();
   }

   public void setVolume(float leftVolume, float rightVolume ) {
       mMediaPlayer.setVolume(leftVolume, rightVolume);
   }

   public boolean isPlaying() {
       return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
   }

   public void stopPlayback() {
       mMediaPlayer.stop();
   }

   public void reset() {
       mMediaPlayer.reset();
   }

   public void release() {
       mMediaPlayer.release();
   }


   @Override
   public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
           int height) {

       mMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(surface));
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
           int height) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

   }
   ```

Comment: the second method solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An easier workaround:

Just add a dummy `parentview` for the `videoview` and set the `visiblity` for that `parentview` instead of changing the `visibility` of the `videoview` itself.